# What's a word that means does not belong, and doesn't matter at the same time?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The word can be used to mean that something doesn't belong (*i.e* in this category) or something that has nothing to do with something, **but also doesn't matter.**

I know there is a word for this in my head but I can't think of it. The definition of the word *belong* is to be rightly placed in a  specified position.

As a context; there was a comment posted on a forum where someone said "so that's what people do in the south" and then that person has a photo of a truck and the person standing next to it (while there was also a video about something silly people might do in the south). I wanted to ask if the comment was a joke because she actually lived in the south (and I was thinking this is possibly true because of the photo). So I wanted to ask if that's true or (then addressing the photo) if the photo of the car _______?

Fill in the blank:

> Is this a joke because you're from the south? And this seems weird to you.  Or is that car photo ________?

It has to be one word that means *doesn't belong and doesn't matter*. I was thinking ***irrelevant, unrelated, inapplicable, unconnected, unassociated, uncorrelated***, etc. Which one fits best? Is there something better? Because I feel like none of them works.

Comment: Take a deep breath and don't do anything rash like study linguistics. It wouldn't show you the answer to this particular conundrum anyway.

Comment: I'm inclined to think your question could have been formulated in a much more concise way.

Comment: Yep I could've been a lot more concise, I suck at language though.

Comment: @Steverebra: I tried to clarify your question. I hope it is ok for you also.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, because it isn't directly. But the concept is very similar to "not even wrong." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be looking for

> **irrelevant** *adj*
>   Unrelated to the matter being considered.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrelevant)

Answer (score 4):

The term ***inconsequential*** should cover your intention:

> **1 a :**  illogical
>      **b :**  irrelevant
>   **2 :**  of no significance :  unimportant
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconsequential))</sub>

But, there is also ***extraneous***:

> **2 a :**  not forming an essential or vital part <extraneous ornamentation>
>      **b :**  having no relevance <an extraneous digression>
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extraneous))</sub>

So, in your sentence:

> ... Or is that car photo *inconsequential*?
>   ... Or is that car photo *extraneous*?

Answer (score 2):

I think [*non sequitur*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/non+sequitur) might fit your needs:

> a statement having little or no relevance to what preceded it; a conclusion that does not follow from the premises. -TFD

Also, [*immaterial*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immaterial) is a possibility:

> of no importance or relevance; inconsequential or irrelevant; of no essential consequence; unimportant.  -TFD

> Is this a joke because you're from the south? And this seems weird to you. Or is that car photo *a non sequitur / immaterial*?

Comment: No but I'm going to remember this because I like it and it's useful.

Comment: The original poster listed "irrelevant" as a word that comes close, but does not quite capture, what they are trying to say. (I'm unable to comment on others' posts as yet).

Comment: The fact that my answer stands at minus one and the other plus two is laughable, considering the latter is comprised of a word already considered and discarded by the original poster.

Comment: Don't take downvotes too personally. You will find that providing explanation, external references, and examples sentences will help generate a positive response. Also, the original poster didn't, in fact, discard "irrelevant." After the list of words that included "irrelevant," there appears "Which one fits best? Is there something better?" So suggesting one of those in the list as the "best" is still answering the question (though I wouldn't vote for it because the answer doesn't address half the question, i.e "but also doesn't matter")

Comment: @Medlin - I would encourage you to ignore downvotes (they aren't directed at you personally; it's arbitrary). I added a link, definition and formatting to your answer, then saw immaterial, which looked suitable as well. I know this is a lot of change. Feel free to rollback. Just trying to get you the attention your answer deserves. Sorry if it's a bit much.

Comment: +1. I believe **immaterial** is the word OP is looking for.